# Wildfly rotate log files during startup

Tags: java, logging, configuration, rotation, wildfly

In `wildfly` currently I've found that logs can be rotated either by time or by filesize. With the last option there is a `rotate-on-boot` configuration property, that if set to true will rotate on each boot of the server.

Is there an already supported option to mix both rotating by time and rotate on each boot of the application server?
Now we use a custom script that makes rotation on each Wildfly startup. I'm looking for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `periodict-size-rotating-file-handler` and leave the `rotate-size` attribute off. Note that if you plan on restarting multiple times a day you'll need to adjust the `max-backup-index` to account for that.

Also there is not automatic purge since it's rotated by a date suffix. Assuming a new date/time was used for the rotation.